# context does not exist:com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.credentialvault.CredentialVaultService liberty profile

Tags: websphere-portal

my portlets are using credential vault and context is looking at -->"portletservice/com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.credentialvault.CredentialVaul‌​tService" . I tried online how i can set this up in liberty profile , but no luck till now .... any suggestion on this would be really helpful .

Error : 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: portletservice/com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.credentialvault.CredentialVaultService

Answer (score 2):

Credential vault is service offered only by the full WebSphere Portal, there is no such service in the WebSphere Liberty as it only has simple portlet container.